# Apache Batik Transcode exception when "&" appears in some text

Tags: java, parsing, svg, batik

I am trying to create a PNG from SVG with batik. In my Proof of Concept it worked smoothly. The code receives and svg escaped, so I have to unescape it before transcoding.

But when there is a tag with "&" (ie "O&M") it fails.

Error:
java.io.IOException: The reference to entity "M" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

& is the beginning of a [character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML). It has to be written `&amp;` in XML files.

Comment: Thanks Robert. My problem was that text was mixed within HTML code. So that I had to convert to code to unescaped html. That's how I fixed.